# Getting the UID of a user model

Tags: usermodel

I want to use the UID to get a user from a url and don't want to use the ID as it is guessable. I know I can do `craft()->users->getUserByUid($uid);` but after getting the uid, the uid is not on the user model which is kinda a pain.

For example what if i wanted the uid for the currently logged in user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Craft doesn't expose the UID in any of its models.

Kind of a pain, but the only thing I can think of as as a workaround is to write a plugin that has a UserModel with the UID and mimics whatever methods from UsersService that you need.

Comment: thanks brad, kinda a pain but yeah ill do a workaround.

Comment: Entirely possible we expose UID to the UserModel at some point, too. Will have to think about any side-effects from doing so.

Comment: i understand security concerns... just as a little background on what I am building: a link in an email that contains the users UID within the link as well as a one time use code to log the user in directly from the email link using userSession->impersonate(). I just wanted to use the UID and Code not the userId and Code -  as the userId is guessable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a user model based on UID you can do this.

For current user..

1. Get current user `$currentUser = craft()->userSession->getUser();`
2. Get user record `$currentUserRecord = $this->_getUserRecordById($currentUser->id);`
3. Add this private function (copied from UserService.php). This will pull the user record by calling `_getUserRecordById` function

   ```
   private function _getUserRecordById($userId)
   {
     $userRecord = UserRecord::model()->findById($userId);
     if (!$userRecord) {
       throw new Exception(Craft::t('No user exists with the ID “{id}”.', array('id' => $userId)));
   }

   return $userRecord;
   }
   ```
4. Now get user UID `$currentUser->uid`

So it'll be similar for any other user. Assuming you have a user id (I'll use `32` for example)

1. Get user record `$userRecord = $this->_getUserRecordById('32');`
2. Now get user UID `$userRecord->uid`

my two cents.

Comment: Its a possible solution but the resulting record is not an element and has no ability to access user custom fields.